# flutter change border color on focus

Tags: flutter

what is the easy way to change border color on focus?
on focus, I want

in border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
child: Icon(...

to be
Colors.yellow

```
MaterialButton(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
    focusColor: Colors.indigo,
    elevation: 0.0,
    //focusNode: myFocusNode,
    child: Container(
      child: new Align(
          alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
          child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                border: Border.all(width: 2, color: Colors.white)),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.search,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          )),
    ),
    onPressed: () async {},
  )
```

Comment: Do you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

bool focus = false;

class teset extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => teset_RunAppPageState();
}

class teset_RunAppPageState extends State<teset> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: MaterialButton(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        focusColor: Colors.indigo,
        elevation: 0.0,
        //focusNode: myFocusNode,
        child: Container(
          child: new Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              child: Container(
                margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                    border: Border.all(
                        width: 2, color: focus ? Colors.white : Colors.yellow)),
                child: Icon(
                  Icons.search,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              )),
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          setState(() {
            focus = !focus;
          });
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Not onPressed, I need to change the color when MaterialButton is focused.

Comment: you mean hover?

Comment: i'm coding for TV, change the color on focus:
the code: 
focusColor: Colors.indigo changes the background color, i need to change the border color.

Comment: Good. Let me check is there anything like that.

Comment: You mean something that, like you tube, when press screen play button arrive and some time after it will go away?

Comment: Fixed it like this: 
focusNode: _node1, in my code above.
bool _focused = false;
  Color _color = Colors.white;
  FocusNode _node1 = FocusNode();
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _node1.requestFocus();
    _node1.addListener(_handleFocusChange);
  }

  void _handleFocusChange() {
    print(_node1.hasFocus);
    if (_node1.hasFocus != _focused) {
      setState(() {
        _focused = _node1.hasFocus;
        _color = Colors.white;
      });
    }
  }